# Unexpected token. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. book?.img ? /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("img",

Tags: reactjs, npm

When I run `npm start` command I get this error:

```
Failed to compile. 

./src/layouts/BookCheckoutPage/BookCheckoutPage.tsx 131:10

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (131:10)

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

|       columnNumber: 21
|     }
>   }, book?.img ? /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("img", {
|     src: book?.img,
|     width: "226",
```

This is my BookCheckoutPage.tsx file:

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import BookModel from "../../models/BookModel";
import { SpinnerLoading } from "../Utils/SpinnerLoading";

export const BookCheckoutPage = () => {

    const [book, setBook] = useState<BookModel>();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [httpError, setHttpError] = useState(null);

    const bookId = (window.location.pathname).split('/')[2];

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchBook = async () => {
            const baseUrl: string = `http://localhost:8080/api/books/${bookId}`;

            const response = await fetch(baseUrl);

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
            }

            const responseJson = await response.json();

            const loadedBook: BookModel = {
                id: responseJson.id,
                title: responseJson.title,
                author: responseJson.author,
                description: responseJson.description,
                copies: responseJson.copies,
                copiesAvailable: responseJson.copiesAvailable,
                category: responseJson.category,
                img: responseJson.img,
            };

            setBook(loadedBook);
            setIsLoading(false);
        };
        fetchBook().catch((error: any) => {
            setIsLoading(false);
            setHttpError(error.message);
        })
    }, []);


    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <SpinnerLoading />
        )
    }

    if (httpError) {
        return (
            <div className='container m-5'>
                <p>{httpError}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='container d-none d-lg-block'>
                <div className='row mt-5'>
                    <div className='col-sm-2 col-md-2'>
                        {book?.img ?
                            <img src={book?.img} width='226' height='349' alt='Book' />
                            :
                            <img src={require('./../../Images/BooksImages/book-luv2code-1000.png')} width='226'
                                height='349' alt='Book' />
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-4 col-md-4 container'>
                        <div className='ml-2'>
                            <h2>{book?.title}</h2>
                            <h5 className='text-primary'>{book?.author}</h5>
                            <p className='lead'>{book?.description}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div className='container d-lg-none mt-5'>
                <div className='d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center'>
                    {book?.img ?
                        <img src={book?.img} width='226' height='349' alt='Book' />
                        :
                        <img src={require('./../../Images/BooksImages/book-luv2code-1000.png')} width='226'
                            height='349' alt='Book' />
                    }
                </div>
                <div className='mt-4'>
                    <div className='ml-2'>
                        <h2>{book?.title}</h2>
                        <h5 className='text-primary'>{book?.author}</h5>
                        <p className='lead'>{book?.description}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I searched the issue, and many posts suggested that is a typescript issue or a tsconfig issue, or `requre()` method issue. I am 100% sure that it's not about that because I already used something similar in my project and did not have any errors. For eg this "ReturnBook".

```
import React from 'react'
import BookModel from '../../models/BookModel'

export const ReturnBook: React.FC<{book: BookModel}> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
      <div className="text-center">
        {props.book.img ? 
           <img
           src={props.book.img}
           width="151"
           height="233"
           alt="book"
          />
          :
          <img
          src={require('../../Images/BooksImages/book-luv2code-1000.png')}
          width="151"
          height="233"
          alt="book"
          />
        }
        <h6 className="mt-2">{props.book.title}</h6>
        <p>{props.book.author}</p>
        <a className="btn main-color text-white" href="#">
          Reserve
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Fixed it:**

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import BookModel from "../../models/BookModel";
import { SpinnerLoading } from "../Utils/SpinnerLoading";

export const BookCheckoutPage = () => {

    const [book, setBook] = useState<BookModel>();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [httpError, setHttpError] = useState(null);

    const bookId = (window.location.pathname).split('/')[2];

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchBook = async () => {
            const baseUrl: string = `http://localhost:8080/api/books/${bookId}`;

            const response = await fetch(baseUrl);

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
            }

            const responseJson = await response.json();

            const loadedBook: BookModel = {
                id: responseJson.id,
                title: responseJson.title,
                author: responseJson.author,
                description: responseJson.description,
                copies: responseJson.copies,
                copiesAvailable: responseJson.copiesAvailable,
                category: responseJson.category,
                img: responseJson.img,
            };

            setBook(loadedBook);
            setIsLoading(false);
        };
        fetchBook().catch((error: any) => {
            setIsLoading(false);
            setHttpError(error.message);
        })
    }, []);


    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <SpinnerLoading />
        )
    }

    if (httpError) {
        return (
            <div className='container m-5'>
                <p>{httpError}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='container d-none d-lg-block'>
                <div className='row mt-5'>
                    <div className='col-sm-2 col-md-2'>
                        {typeof book !== 'undefined' && book.img ?
                            <img src={book.img} width='226' height='349' alt='Book' />
                            :
                            <img src={require('./../../Images/BooksImages/book-luv2code-1000.png')} width='226'
                                height='349' alt='Book' />
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className='col-4 col-md-4 container'>
                        <div className='ml-2'>
                            <h2>{typeof book !== 'undefined' && book.title}</h2>
                            <h5 className='text-primary'>{typeof book !== 'undefined' && book.author}</h5>
                            <p className='lead'>{typeof book !== 'undefined' && book.description}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div className='container d-lg-none mt-5'>
                <div className='d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center'>
                    {typeof book !== 'undefined' && book.img ?
                        <img src={book.img} width='226' height='349' alt='Book' />
                        :
                        <img src={require('./../../Images/BooksImages/book-luv2code-1000.png')} width='226'
                            height='349' alt='Book' />
                    }
                </div>
                <div className='mt-4'>
                    <div className='ml-2'>
                        <h2>{typeof book !== 'undefined' && book.title}</h2>
                        <h5 className='text-primary'>{typeof book !== 'undefined' && book.author}</h5>
                        <p className='lead'>{typeof book !== 'undefined' && book.description}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```